# Undefined reference to function multiple error

Tags: c++, function

I'm pretty new to C++ and I need to run a code to communicate via GPIB to an external instrument, so I'm using manual's example through Dev-C++:

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <visa.h> //optional
#include "wgfmu.h"
void checkError(int ret) // 7
{
if(ret < WGFMU_NO_ERROR) {
throw ret;
}
}
int checkError2(int ret) //14
{
if( ret < WGFMU_NO_ERROR ) {
 int size;
 WGFMU_getErrorSize(&size);
 char* msg = new char[size + 1];
 WGFMU_getError(msg, &size);
 fprintf(stderr, "%s", msg );
 delete [] msg;
}
return ret;
}

static const int VISA_ERROR_OFFSET = WGFMU_ERROR_CODE_MIN - 1;
void checkError3(int ret) //29
{
if(ret < WGFMU_NO_ERROR && ret >= WGFMU_ERROR_CODE_MIN || ret < VISA_ERROR_OFFSET) {
throw ret;
}
}
void writeResults(int channelId, const char* fileName) //36
{
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
if(fp != 0) {
int measuredSize, totalSize;
WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(channelId, &measuredSize, &totalSize);
for(int i = 0; i < measuredSize; i++) {
double time, value;
WGFMU_getMeasureValue(channelId, i, &time, &value);
fprintf(fp, "%.9lf, %.9lf\n", time, value);
}
fclose(fp);
}
}
void writeResults2(int channelId, int offset, int size, const char* fileName) //51
{
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
if(fp != 0) {
int measuredSize, totalSize;
WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(channelId, &measuredSize, &totalSize);
for(int i = offset; i < offset + size; i++) {
double time, value;
WGFMU_getMeasureValue(channelId, i, &time, &value);
fprintf(fp, "%.9lf, %.9lf\n", time, value);
}
fclose(fp);
}
}

void writeResults3(int channelId1, int channelId2, int offset, int size, const
char* fileName) //66
{
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
if(fp != 0) {
int measuredSize, totalSize;
WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(channelId2, &measuredSize, &totalSize);
for(int i = offset; i < offset + size; i++) {
double time, value, voltage;
WGFMU_getMeasureValue(channelId2, i, &time, &value);
WGFMU_getInterpolatedForceValue(channelId1, time, &voltage);
fprintf(fp, "%.9lf, %.9lf\n", voltage, value);
}
fclose(fp);
}
}
int main() //82
{
// Insert your code here

// OFFLINE
WGFMU_clear(); // 9
WGFMU_createPattern("pulse", 0); // 0 ms, 0 V
WGFMU_addVector("pulse", 0.0001, 1); //0.1 ms, 1 V
WGFMU_addVector("pulse", 0.0004, 1); //0.5 ms, 1 V
WGFMU_addVector("pulse", 0.0001, 0); //0.6 ms, 0 V
WGFMU_addVector("pulse", 0.0004, 0); //1.0 ms, 0 V
WGFMU_addSequence(101, "pulse", 10); //10 pulse output //15
// ONLINE
WGFMU_openSession("GPIB0::17::INSTR"); //18
WGFMU_initialize();
WGFMU_setOperationMode(101, WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_FASTIV);
WGFMU_connect(101);
WGFMU_execute();
WGFMU_waitUntilCompleted();
WGFMU_initialize(); // WGFMU_disconnect(101); //24
WGFMU_closeSession();
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
D:\folder\main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getErrorSize(int*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getError(char*, int*)'
main.o: In function `writeResults(int, char const*)':
D:\folder\main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(int, int*, int*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValue(int, int, double*, double*)'
main.o: In function `writeResults2(int, int, int, char const*)':
D:\folder\main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(int, int*, int*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:54: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValue(int, int, double*, double*)'
main.o: In function `writeResults3(int, int, int, int, char const*)':
D:\folder\main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(int, int*, int*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:70: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getMeasureValue(int, int, double*, double*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getInterpolatedForceValue(int, double, double*)'
main.o: In function `main':
D:\folder\main.cpp:82: undefined reference to `WGFMU_clear()'
D:\folder\main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `WGFMU_createPattern(char const*, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:84: undefined reference to `WGFMU_addVector(char const*, double, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:85: undefined reference to `WGFMU_addVector(char const*, double, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `WGFMU_addVector(char const*, double, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:87: undefined reference to `WGFMU_addVector(char const*, double, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:88: undefined reference to `WGFMU_addSequence(int, char const*, double)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `WGFMU_openSession(char const*)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:91: undefined reference to `WGFMU_initialize()'
D:\folder\main.cpp:92: undefined reference to `WGFMU_setOperationMode(int, int)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:93: undefined reference to `WGFMU_connect(int)'
D:\folder\main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `WGFMU_execute()'
D:\folder\main.cpp:95: undefined reference to `WGFMU_waitUntilCompleted()'
D:\folder\main.cpp:96: undefined reference to `WGFMU_initialize()'
D:\folder\main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `WGFMU_closeSession()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

D:\folder\Makefile.win:26: recipe for target 'Proyecto2.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Proyecto2.exe] Error 1
```

While wgfmu.h is located in the same folder:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Distributed by Agilent Technologies                                       */
/*                                                                           */
/* Do not modify the contents of this file.                                  */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                                           */
/* Title   : WGFMU.H                                                         */
/* Date    : 10-30-2008                                                      */
/* Purpose : B1530A (WGFMU) Instrument Library API and Constant Definitions  */
/*           for Microsoft Visual C++ .NET                                   */
/*                                                                           */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ifndef WGFMU_INSTRUMENTLIBRARY_H
#define WGFMU_INSTRUMENTLIBRARY_H

#define WGFMUAPI _stdcall

// API Return Value - Error Code
static const int WGFMU_NO_ERROR                         = 0;
static const int WGFMU_PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE_ERROR     = -1;
static const int WGFMU_ILLEGAL_STRING_ERROR             = -2;
static const int WGFMU_CONTEXT_ERROR                    = -3;
static const int WGFMU_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERROR     = -4;
static const int WGFMU_COMMUNICATION_ERROR              = -5;
static const int WGFMU_FW_ERROR                         = -6;
static const int WGFMU_LIBRARY_ERROR                    = -7;
static const int WGFMU_ERROR                            = -8;
static const int WGFMU_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND_ERROR          = -9;
static const int WGFMU_PATTERN_NOT_FOUND_ERROR          = -10;
static const int WGFMU_EVENT_NOT_FOUND_ERROR            = -11;
static const int WGFMU_PATTERN_ALREADY_EXISTS_ERROR     = -12;
static const int WGFMU_SEQUENCER_NOT_RUNNING_ERROR      = -13;
static const int WGFMU_RESULT_NOT_READY_ERROR           = -14;
static const int WGFMU_RESULT_OUT_OF_DATE               = -15;

static const int WGFMU_ERROR_CODE_MIN                   = -9999;

// WGFMU_doSelfCaliration, WGFMU_doSelfTest
static const int WGFMU_PASS = 0;
static const int WGFMU_FAIL = 1;

// WGFMU_treatWarningsAsErrors, WGFMU_setWarningLevel
static const int WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFFSET             = 1000;
static const int WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFF                = WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_SEVERE             = WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_NORMAL             = WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_INFORMATION        = WGFMU_WARNING_LEVEL_OFFSET + 3;

// WGFMU_setOperationMode
static const int WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_OFFSET            = 2000;
static const int WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_DC                = WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_FASTIV            = WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_PG                = WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_SMU               = WGFMU_OPERATION_MODE_OFFSET + 3;

// WGFMU_setForceVoltageRange
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET       = 3000;
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_AUTO         = WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3V           = WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_5V           = WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_10V_NEGATIVE = WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 3;
static const int WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_10V_POSITIVE = WGFMU_FORCE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 4;

// WGFMU_setMeasureMode
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_MODE_OFFSET              = 4000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_MODE_VOLTAGE             = WGFMU_MEASURE_MODE_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_MODE_CURRENT             = WGFMU_MEASURE_MODE_OFFSET + 1;

// WGFMU_setMeasureVoltageRange
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET     = 5000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_5V         = WGFMU_MEASURE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_10V        = WGFMU_MEASURE_VOLTAGE_RANGE_OFFSET + 2;

// WGFMU_setMeasureCurrentRange
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET     = 6000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_1UA        = WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_10UA       = WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_100UA      = WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET + 3;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_1MA        = WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET + 4;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_10MA       = WGFMU_MEASURE_CURRENT_RANGE_OFFSET + 5;

// WGFMU_setMeasureEnabled
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_ENABLED_OFFSET           = 7000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_ENABLED_DISABLE          = WGFMU_MEASURE_ENABLED_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_ENABLED_ENABLE           = WGFMU_MEASURE_ENABLED_OFFSET + 1;

// WGFMU_setTriggerOutMode
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET          = 8000;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_DISABLE         = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_START_EXECUTION = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_START_SEQUENCE  = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_START_PATTERN   = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET + 3;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_EVENT           = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_MODE_OFFSET + 4;

static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_POLARITY_OFFSET      = 8100;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_POLARITY_POSITIVE    = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_POLARITY_OFFSET+ 0;
static const int WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_POLARITY_NEGATIVE    = WGFMU_TRIGGER_OUT_POLARITY_OFFSET+ 1;

// WGFMU_createMergedPattern
static const int WGFMU_AXIS_OFFSET                      = 9000;
static const int WGFMU_AXIS_TIME                        = WGFMU_AXIS_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_AXIS_VOLTAGE                     = WGFMU_AXIS_OFFSET + 1;

// WGFMU_getStatus, WGFMU_getChannelStatus
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET                    = 10000;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_COMPLETED                 = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_DONE                      = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 1;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_RUNNING                   = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 2;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_ABORT_COMPLETED           = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 3;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_ABORTED                   = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 4;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_RUNNING_ILLEGAL           = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 5;
static const int WGFMU_STATUS_IDLE                      = WGFMU_STATUS_OFFSET + 6;

// WGFMU_isMeasureEventCompleted
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_OFFSET             = 11000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_NOT_COMPLETED      = WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_COMPLETED          = WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_OFFSET + 1;

// WGFMU_setMeasureEvent
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_DATA_OFFSET        = 12000;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_DATA_AVERAGED      = WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_DATA_OFFSET + 0;
static const int WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_DATA_RAW           = WGFMU_MEASURE_EVENT_DATA_OFFSET + 1;

// Common - Initialize

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_openSession(const char* address);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_closeSession();
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_initialize();
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setTimeout(double timeout);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_doSelfCalibration(int* result, char* detail, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_doSelfTest(int* result, char* detail, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getChannelIdSize(int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getChannelIds(int* channelIds, int* size);

// Common - Error and Warning

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getErrorSize(int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getError(char* error, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getErrorSummarySize(int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getErrorSummary(char* errorSummary, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_treatWarningsAsErrors(int warningLevel);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setWarningLevel(int warningLevel);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getWarningLevel(int* warningLevel);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getWarningSummarySize(int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getWarningSummary(char* warningSummary, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_openLogFile(const char* fileName);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_closeLogFile();

// Common - Setup

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setOperationMode(int channelId,int operationMode);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getOperationMode(int channelId, int* operationMode);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setForceVoltageRange(int channelId, int forceVoltageRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getForceVoltageRange(int channelId, int* forceVoltageRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureMode(int channelId, int measureMode);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureMode(int channelId, int* measureMode);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureVoltageRange(int channelId, int measureVoltageRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureVoltageRange(int channelId, int* measureVoltageRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureCurrentRange(int channelId, int measureCurrentRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureCurrentRange(int channelId, int* measureCurrentRange);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setForceDelay(int channelId, double forceDelay);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getForceDelay(int channelId, double* forceDelay);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureDelay(int channelId, double measureDelay);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureDelay(int channelId, double* measureDelay);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureEnabled(int channelId, int measureEnabled);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_isMeasureEnabled(int channelId, int* measureEnabled);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setTriggerOutMode(int channelId, int triggerOutMode, int polarity);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getTriggerOutMode(int channelId, int* triggerOutMode, int* polarity);

// Common - Measurement

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_connect(int channelId);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_disconnect(int channelId);

// WGFMU - Initialize

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_clear();

// WGFMU - Setup - Pattern

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_createPattern(const char* patternName, double initialVoltage);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_addVector(const char* patternName, double deltaTime, double voltage);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_addVectors(const char* patternName, double* deltaTimes, double* voltages, int size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setVector(const char* patternName, double time, double voltage);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setVectors(const char* patternName, double* times, double* voltages, int size);

// WGFMU - Setup - Pattern Opeartion

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_createMergedPattern(const char* patternName, const char* pattern1, const char* pattern2, int axis);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_createMultipliedPattern(const char* patternName, const char* pattern1, double timeFactor, double voltageFactor);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_createOffsetPattern(const char* patternName, const char* pattern1, double timeOffset, double voltageOffset);

// WGFMU - Setup - Event
    
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setMeasureEvent(const char* patternName, const char* eventName, double time, int measurementPoints, double measurementInterval, double averagingTime, int rawData);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setRangeEvent(const char* patternName, const char* eventName, double time, int rangeIndex);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_setTriggerOutEvent(const char* patternName, const char* eventName, double time, double duration);

// WGFMU - Setup - Sequence

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_addSequence(int channelId, const char* patternName, double loopCount);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_addSequences(int channelId, const char** patternNames, double* loopCounts, int size);

// WGFMU - Setup Check - Pattern

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternForceValueSize(const char* patternName, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternForceValues(const char* patternName, int offset, int* size, double* forceTimes, double* forceValues);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternForceValue(const char* patternName, int index, double* forceTime, double* forceValue);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternInterpolatedForceValue(const char* patternName, double time, double* forceValue);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternMeasureTimeSize(const char* patternName, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternMeasureTimes(const char* patternName, int offset, int* size, double* measureTimes);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getPatternMeasureTime(const char* patternName, int index, double* measureTime);

// WGFMU - Setup Check - Sequence

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getForceValueSize(int channelId, double* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getForceValues(int channelId, double offset, int* size, double* forceTimes, double* forceValues);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getForceValue(int channelId, double index, double* forceTime, double* forceValue);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getInterpolatedForceValue(int channelId, double time, double* forceValue);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureTimeSize(int channelId, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureTimes(int channelId, int offset, int* size, double* measureTimes);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureTime(int channelId, int index, double* measureTime);

// WGFMU - Setup Check - Event

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureEventSize(int channelId, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureEvents(int channelId, int offset, int* size, char** patternNames, char** eventNames, int* cycles, double* loops, int* counts, int* offsets, int* sizes);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureEvent(int channelId, int index, char* patternName, char* eventName, int* cycle, double* loop, int* count, int* offset, int* size);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureEventAttribute(int channelId, int index, double* time, int* measurementPoints, double* measurementInterval, double* averagingTime, int* rawData);

// WGFMU - Import / Export

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_exportAscii(const char* fileName);

// WGFMU - Measurement

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_update();
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_updateChannel(int channelId);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_execute();
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_abort();
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_abortChannel(int channelId);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getStatus(int* status, double* elapsedTime, double* totalTime);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getChannelStatus(int channelId, int* status, double* elapsedTime, double* totalTime);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_waitUntilCompleted();

// WGFMU - Data Retrieve - Measure Value

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureValueSize(int channelId, int* measuredSize, int* totalSize);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureValues(int channelId, int offset, int* size, double* measureTimes, double* measureValues);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getMeasureValue(int channelId, int index, double* measureTime, double* measureValue);

// WGFMU - Data Retrieve - Measure Event

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_getCompletedMeasureEventSize(int channelId, int* measuredSize, int* totalSize);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_isMeasureEventCompleted(int channelId, const char* patternName, const char* eventName, int cycle, double loop, int count, int* completed, int* index, int* offset, int* size);

// DC - Measure

int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_dcforceVoltage(int channelId, double voltage);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_dcmeasureValue(int channelId, double* value);
int WGFMUAPI WGFMU_dcmeasureAveragedValue(int channelId, int count, int interval, double* value);

#endif//WGFMU_INSTRUMENTLIBRARY_H
```

Sorry in advance, that's my first try using C++ and I just can't execute it. I've followed manual's instructions when creating the project but still get the same results.

Comment: Do you have these methods implementations? as it seems it doesn't find the relevant symbols

Comment: This is what I did:

1. Create a new Win32 project in Dev-C++
2. Paste the above code in .cpp file
3. Paste wgfmu.h in the same folder
4. Execute & errors: undefined reference to the functions

Answer (score 1):

In the attached wgfmu.h file you only have the declaration of several methods, but you don't have the definition of these methods.

So in linkage time it will fail to find the implementation and will fail.

For example: D:\folder\main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `WGFMU_getErrorSize(int*)'
You call this function in "checkError2" but you have a declaration of that function and you don't have the definition (implementation) of it.

That is why the linkage complains about undefined reference.